# Calling another render method to render a subview in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I have two templates, one is the parent template, and the other is a template that has the subviews in it.  My first parent view extends backbone's view and its render method looks like

```
render: function () {
  this.$el.append(templates["template-parent-test"](this.model));
  return this;
}
```

This parent view has a button on it.  The button right now I use to populate my view.  It basically does this:

```
   populateView: function () {
   // create some dummy test data to match the web service
     _.each(myModel, function (theModel) {
         var testView = new childView({ model: theModel });
         this.$('div-in-parent-view').append(testView.render().$el);
     });
   }
```

This backbone view extends the Backbone.View and its render method looks like:

```
    render: function () {
        console.log("rendering child view");
        this.$el.html(this.template({ data: this.model.toJSON() }));

        return this;
    }
```

So this works.  But I don't want to populate the parent view on a button press.  I want to populate it when I show it for the first time and have the button do what its actually supposed to do.  I would think that I could just call this.populateView() from my render function in the parent view, but nothing actually gets rendered.  But if I do this.populateView() in my button event, it gets rendered.  Why is there a difference here?  Thanks.

Comment: What exactly happens when you call `this.populateView` in the parent view's `render` after `this.$el.append`? Is myModel empty at that point? I am guessing that in the parent's render myModel is empty, but when the button is clicked enough time has passed and the collection is filled.

Comment: @PaulHoenecke No myModel is not empty at that point.  I'm not actually talking to a web service yet.  I just wanted to mock up the view in order to talk to the web service.  So I actually just create some dummy test data.  I actually log that data in my code that I didn't include and the model data is all there.

Comment: And `myModel` is defined somewhere? In the code you show it looks like either a global or local variable and not a property of the view.  I guess that would not be the problem, since you say it works from the button click.  I think you should show more of the code, and in the state that produces the problem.

Comment: @PaulHoenecke Yeah the //create some dummy test data was written so I didn't actually have to c&p my models in there.  So I guess that's what I was trying to determine, is if logically, I should be able to call this method to render the subviews in my rendering of the parent view and if that should be ok assuming I knew what I was doing with backbone :P.  Since it worked on the button click, I assumed I could just put it in my parent's render function.  That was the part I was most confused on.

Comment: Yes you should be able to do that in the parent's render method. Seems the problem is in some other code. You see the logging from `console.log("rendering child view");` ?

Comment: @PaulHoenecke Yeah and I logged the data to the console and inspected it in Firebug.  So I see the object on the console even though my parent view does not show the views.

Comment: Also, `this.$('div-in-parent-view')` is not valid.  If that is an id you need the # in front. But again, if the code you posted is not the real code that shows the problem, it is hard to find an answer. If that was the problem it wouldn't work on button click either.

Comment: Try adding `this` as a [third parameter to `each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each).  That sets the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `this` as a [third parameter to `each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each). That sets the context. When you don't specify the context, `this` will be `window`.  And since your html is not yet on the page during the parent view's `render`, it wont find `this.$('#div-in-parent-view')` in order to add the html to it.

Comment: Thanks!  How do you know this stuff so well?!?!?!?!?!  Hahah.  Thanks again!